# What is the unit of measure for timeTaken_d in Azure diagnostics?

Tags: azure, azure-monitor

I want to get a list of all requests that are taking longer then 2 seconds and I think this is correct as the `timeTaken_d` appears to be a floating point and would seem to be in seconds.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess" and timeTaken_d  > 2
| project TimeGenerated, host_s, requestUri_s, httpStatus_d, backendPoolName_s, serverRouted_s, timeTaken_d 
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

However, I have seen elsewhere that this measure is in milliseconds.

Does anyone know for sure? Better still, can someone point me at the docs?

Answer (score 1):

It's in milliseconds, as per this [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404).

> timeTaken:    Length of time (in milliseconds) that it takes for a request
> to be processed and its response to be sent. This is calculated as the
> interval from the time when Application Gateway receives the first
> byte of an HTTP request to the time when the response send operation
> finishes. It's important to note that the Time-Taken field usually
> includes the time that the request and response packets are traveling
> over the network.

Comment: Thing is... this is not what we're actually seeing for timeTaken_d when compared to the IIS logs - we're seeing floating values which are much nearer seconds - e.g. 2.34 from azure and >2000 in IIS logs for seemingly same request - although it's hard to tie it down 100%

One thing is for sure... if Azure if reporting milliseconds then it's not at all representative of the time IIS thinks it's taking to serve requests.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as [Mark](https://serverfault.com/users/85232/mark) and found the documentation provided by [Sam](https://serverfault.com/users/48/sam-cogan) helpful. However I wanted to point out that timeTaken_d is reported in different units for WAF_v1 (milliseconds) and WAF_v2 (seconds). In Azure Portal you can see what tier you're on by looking at the Configuration section of your Application Gateway.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics#for-application-gateway-and-waf-v2-sku

Answer (score 0):

The time in timeTaken_d field is measured in milliseconds.

The requested info is under "analyzing the Logs" section in below document -

https://cbeveridge.co.uk/2020/03/07/troubleshooting-azure-gateway-web-application-firewall-waf-logs/

Comment: In that article it looks to be milliseconds.... however we're seeing (for IIS requests), floating point numbers which are much closer to IIS's own log number / 1000